# ThinkTecture Identity Server and WebDAV

Tags: c#, webdav, thinktecture-ident-server

Following is something that I want to implement:

- Custom WebDAV Module that handles all the WebDAV requests and serves the user based on our internal logic.
- OAuth with ThinkTecture Identity Server to access the WebDAV

We have configured the ThinkTecture ID server to work with OAuth and use Facebook/Google as Identity Providers with the Relying Party being the WebDAV URL.
Now when we do the Get Request from Browser, the client is redirected to ThinkTecture HRD and user gets authenticated and custom response is given back.

But when we try to use other clients like Office 2010/ Mini - Redirector than it asks us to provide a certificate to access, also I read the blog by BrockAllen [here](http://brockallen.com/2012/10/18/cors-iis-and-webdav/), where he says that we have to remove the WebDAV module from Web.Config in-order to get the IDP working.
can anyone help me out in what we are trying to acheive? is it possible to use the WebDAV with ThinkTecture as Identity Provider?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one which you are looking of
http://www.webdavsystem.com/

I have been using it in my projects and it's just awesome.